# conexion a mysql remoto (red local) no funciona

Tags: c#, mysql

Mi aplicativo se debe conectar a MySQL que reside en un equipo de mi red local, con IP estática.

En la cadena de conexión de mi clase `conexion` coloco la IP de ese computador, pero es imposible conectarme.

mi cadena la tengo asi:

```
public static string cadenaConexion = "Server=192.168.XX.XXX; Database=XXXX; UID=XXX; Pwd=XXX; Port= 3306; ";
```

Me estaré saltando algún parámetro?

saludos a todos y gracias desde ya

Comment: y que error obtienes?

Comment: ¿cuál sistema operativo utilizas?¿Ya lo probaste localmente y si funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy probable que se trate de permisos si es que tu aplicativo trabajaba correctamente de forma local. Tienes que activar el acceso remoto a mysql en la configuración de mysql.

Primero debes modificar el archivo my.cnf (la ubicación de este dependerá de tu sistema operativo. Asumimos linux, sino solo cambian las rutas, lo demás es lo mismo):

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

y descomentar las siguientes lineas.

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

y reiniciar el servicio de mysql

```
~ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Después debes dar privilegio de acceso remoto al usuario (`database` es el nombre de las base, `user` el usuario de DB y `password` la contraseña):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

o si quieres una ip en especifico (`1.2.3.4` es la IP)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'1.2.3.4'
IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

y después:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Para probar que se puede accesar remotamente (`HOST` es la IP o el nombre de dominio al quequeremos accesar y `USER` es el usuario de la BD):

```
mysql -h HOST -u USER -p
```